# Place the items of a dataset by using the scales in d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, scale

I have to do something like that in SVG:

[image]

As you can see, it's basically a table.
I think to use d3.js and it's scales to draw and positionate each element but I need some help.
I don't know how to start.

suppose I have a linear scale to position items horizontally and another one to position elements vertically:

```
const myDomainH = ?
const myRangeH = ?
const scaleHorizontally = d3.scaleLinear().domain(myDomainH).range(myRangeH)

const myDomainV = ?
const myRangeV = ?
const scaleVertically = d3.scaleLinear().domain(myDomainV).range(myRangeV)
```

and my dataset is:

```
[
  [
    {
      "category": "Category 1",
      "color": 1,
      "value": 73.55989924542436,
      "objects": [
        {
          "object": "Object 11",
          "value": 70.77137994021379
        },
        {
          "object": "Object 12",
          "value": 81.4082571028975
        },
        {
          "object": "Object 13",
          "value": 70.77137994021379
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "category": "Category 1",
      "color": 2,
      "value": 22.2597985833491,
      "objects": [
        {
          "object": "Object 11",
          "value": 15.853930976590469
        },
        {
          "object": "Object 12",
          "value": 56.56972660299733
        },
        {
          "object": "Object 13",
          "value": 70.77137994021379
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "category": "Category 1",
      "color": 3,
      "value": 22.709698156338032,
      "objects": [
        {
          "object": "Object 11",
          "value": 74.99319041632756
        },
        {
          "object": "Object 12",
          "value": 68.41322493812694
        },
        {
          "object": "Object 13",
          "value": 70.77137994021379
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "category": "Category 1",
      "color": 4,
      "value": 23.66413869920101,
      "objects": [
        {
          "object": "Object 11",
          "value": 17.61500366859401
        },
        {
          "object": "Object 12",
          "value": 11.147400814940344
        },
        {
          "object": "Object 13",
          "value": 70.77137994021379
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "category": "Category 1",
      "color": 5,
      "value": 45.82962655452327,
      "objects": [
        {
          "object": "Object 11",
          "value": 9.967028966701474
        },
        {
          "object": "Object 12",
          "value": 13.944328943444905
        },
        {
          "object": "Object 13",
          "value": 70.77137994021379
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "category": "Category 1",
      "color": 6,
      "value": 24.865266198819302,
      "objects": [
        {
          "object": "Object 11",
          "value": 37.45282918258137
        },
        {
          "object": "Object 12",
          "value": 62.40512982903728
        },
        {
          "object": "Object 13",
          "value": 70.77137994021379
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "category": "Category 2",
      "color": 1,
      "value": 35.30633472871503,
      "objects": [
        {
          "object": "Object 21",
          "value": 32.017889605115336
        },
        {
          "object": "Object 22",
          "value": 22.600901269005913
        },
      ]
    },
    {
      "category": "Category 2",
      "color": 2,
      "value": 15.763575845434152,
      "objects": [
        {
          "object": "Object 21",
          "value": 32.017889605115336
        },
        {
          "object": "Object 22",
          "value": 22.600901269005913
        },
      ]
    },
    {
      "category": "Category 2",
      "color": 3,
      "value": 65.66932804750859,
      "objects": [
        {
          "object": "Object 21",
          "value": 32.017889605115336
        },
        {
          "object": "Object 22",
          "value": 22.600901269005913
        },
      ]
    },
    {
      "category": "Category 2",
      "color": 4,
      "value": 35.79326347817449,
      "objects": [
        {
          "object": "Object 21",
          "value": 32.017889605115336
        },
        {
          "object": "Object 22",
          "value": 22.600901269005913
        },
      ]
    },
    {
      "category": "Category 2",
      "color": 5,
      "value": 91.79806542930078,
      "objects": [
        {
          "object": "Object 21",
          "value": 32.017889605115336
        },
        {
          "object": "Object 22",
          "value": 22.600901269005913
        },
      ]
    },
    {
      "category": "Category 2",
      "color": 6,
      "value": 34.574064983647766,
      "objects": [
        {
          "object": "Object 21",
          "value": 32.017889605115336
        },
        {
          "object": "Object 22",
          "value": 22.600901269005913
        },
      ]
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "category": "Category 3",
      "color": 1,
      "value": 57.64950041773291,
      "objects": [
        {
          "object": "Object 31",
          "value": 42.86818415221803
        },
        {
          "object": "Object 32",
          "value": 42.86818415221803
        },
        {
          "object": "Object 33",
          "value": 42.86818415221803
        },
        {
          "object": "Object 34",
          "value": 42.86818415221803
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "category": "Category 3",
      "color": 2,
      "value": 17.76033855108046,
      "objects": [
        {
          "object": "Object 31",
          "value": 89.52070065904911
        },
        {
          "object": "Object 32",
          "value": 42.86818415221803
        },
        {
          "object": "Object 33",
          "value": 42.86818415221803
        },
        {
          "object": "Object 34",
          "value": 42.86818415221803
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "category": "Category 3",
      "color": 3,
      "value": 11.845610356899815,
      "objects": [
        {
          "object": "Object 31",
          "value": 54.76278304243267
        },
        {
          "object": "Object 32",
          "value": 42.86818415221803
        },
        {
          "object": "Object 33",
          "value": 42.86818415221803
        },
        {
          "object": "Object 34",
          "value": 42.86818415221803
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "category": "Category 3",
      "color": 4,
      "value": 80.55423937728892,
      "objects": [
        {
          "object": "Object 31",
          "value": 63.74492886059537
        },
        {
          "object": "Object 32",
          "value": 42.86818415221803
        },
        {
          "object": "Object 33",
          "value": 42.86818415221803
        },
        {
          "object": "Object 34",
          "value": 42.86818415221803
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "category": "Category 3",
      "color": 5,
      "value": 3.6629102311577455,
      "objects": [
        {
          "object": "Object 31",
          "value": 63.260999161538535
        },
        {
          "object": "Object 32",
          "value": 42.86818415221803
        },
        {
          "object": "Object 33",
          "value": 42.86818415221803
        },
        {
          "object": "Object 34",
          "value": 42.86818415221803
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "category": "Category 3",
      "color": 6,
      "value": 66.08487065166841,
      "objects": [
        {
          "object": "Object 31",
          "value": 70.16436770369718
        },
        {
          "object": "Object 32",
          "value": 42.86818415221803
        },
        {
          "object": "Object 33",
          "value": 42.86818415221803
        },
        {
          "object": "Object 34",
          "value": 42.86818415221803
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
]
```

(ignores the field `value` that is not used for the moment).

and then?

With these data, I have to create and position the cells (svg rects) and the written using d3.js.
The idea is to have a responsive page then the cells will have the width that resizes based on the width of the page.

Then i thought that the horizontal scale could have as a range the width of the `window.innerwidht`) but I don't know if it is correct.

The height of the svg rects must be fixed to `15px`.

In any case, I don't know how to proceed. Someone could give me help?

Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are drawing a nested structure, and the trick here, is that while for outter layer you use `.data(dataSet)`, for inner layers you have to approach by extracting its data from the already mapped outter layer element with a function, e.g. when outter layer is columns, and inner layer is cells: `.data(function(d) { return d.objects; }`.

As far as positioning itself goes, I recommend heavy utilization of `g` elements with `transform` attributes. This way, when you are inside inner layer, you don't have to worry about positioning of its outter layer element (so e.g. when you're drawing a cell, you don't need to know the `x` offset of the column). For calculating position, the pointScale might make more sense in this context, though it doesn't really matter that much.

> Then i thought that the horizontal scale could have as a range the width of the window.innerwidht) but I don't know if it is correct.

Yes, that's a right approach. Most likely you'll want to have rendering done by putting it inside a single method (by which I mean it's the only exposed point to invoke rendering; ofcourse it will and should delegate parts of it for private methods), and you'd call that method in the resize event listener.

Here is some code to get you started; it creates a table for a single category. To create multiple categories, you'll have to apply same logic -- nest table logic inside the category, by extracting it's data via function from the passed category data.

```
var dataSet = [{
    "category": "Category 1",
    "color": 1,
    "value": 73.55989924542436,
    "objects": [{
        "object": "Object 11",
        "value": 70.77137994021379
      },
      {
        "object": "Object 12",
        "value": 81.4082571028975
      },
      {
        "object": "Object 13",
        "value": 70.77137994021379
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "category": "Category 1",
    "color": 2,
    "value": 22.2597985833491,
    "objects": [{
        "object": "Object 11",
        "value": 15.853930976590469
      },
      {
        "object": "Object 12",
        "value": 56.56972660299733
      },
      {
        "object": "Object 13",
        "value": 70.77137994021379
      }
    ]
  }
];

var svg = d3.select('svg');
var winWidth = 300;

var colScale = d3.scalePoint()
  .domain(dataSet.map(function(d) {
    return d.color;
  }))
  .range([0, winWidth]);


var objects = dataSet[0].objects.map(function(o) {
  return o.object;
});

var cellScale = d3.scalePoint()
  .domain(objects)
  .range([0, objects.length * 15]);

var columns = svg.selectAll('g.column')
  .data(dataSet);

columns = columns.enter()
  .append('g')
  .classed('column', true)
  .merge(columns)
  .attr('transform', function(d, i) {
    return 'translate(' + colScale(d.color) + ',0)';
  });

var cells = columns
  .selectAll('g.cell')
  .data(function(d) {
    return d.objects;
  });

cells = cells.enter()
  .append('g')
  .classed('cell', true)
  .merge(cells)
  .attr('transform', function(d, i) {
    return 'translate(0,' + cellScale(d.object) + ')';
  });

cells.append('rect')
  //Styles should be in CSS
  .style('fill', 'none')
  .style('stroke', 'black')
  .attr('width', colScale.step())
  .attr('height', cellScale.step());

cells.append('text')
  .style('dominant-baseline', 'text-before-edge')
  .text(function(d) {
    return d.value;
  });
```

Comment: Yeah, though you don't see the second column because svg size is too small. Try adding `body, html, svg { width: 100%; }` to the stylesheet